# how to Customize windows 8.1 camera app for C# wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating WPF application, for my webcam section am using built-in metro camera app. Since this application is an Desktop application, i just want to use Metro Camera app for the sake of capturing Image and editing. After capturing the images its getting saved in This PC-->Pictures folder, but i want to save the images in some other folder and also i want to give a name for the images manually. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did the updated answer work for you?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858376/download-and-save-image-in-pictures-library-through-windows-8-metro-xaml-app) is not working...

Comment: It should worked. You probably do something wrong somewhere. Try to review again and also read the other link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for saving images :

```
    void SaveToBmp(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
{
    var encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    SaveUsingEncoder(visual, fileName, encoder);
}

void SaveToPng(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
{
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    SaveUsingEncoder(visual, fileName, encoder);
}

// and so on for other encoders (if you want)


void SaveUsingEncoder(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)visual.ActualWidth, (int)visual.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bitmap.Render(visual);
    BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
    encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

    using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470841/easiest-way-of-saving-wpf-image-control-to-a-file) is the source for that.

Update :

If you want to save images in `metro app` you can use `Pictures Library` for that.

Read these following questions for that :

[Download and Save image in Pictures Library through Windows 8 Metro XAML App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858376/download-and-save-image-in-pictures-library-through-windows-8-metro-xaml-app)

[How save photo capture windows 8 c# metro app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566376/how-save-photo-capture-windows-8-c-sharp-metro-app)

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Ranjith I already answered that question. You only need to get images then you can easily use the codes for saving images.

Comment: actually am using built in metro app, its a seperate process, how can i change that path of saving images as per my requirement?

Comment: i am not developing Metro app (windows store app), am creating Wpf application which will be use for Tablet devices, am using Built-in metro app that is Camera app for taking pictures. My question is can i save the images which is taken by metro camera app in some other folder with custom name?